# Model validation not working on date fields in Cakephp 1.3

Tags: forms, validation, date, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to ensure that a date is entered in the date fields in my form.

The model validations are working correctly on all fields except the dates.

Here is an example of my model validation:

```
var $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Title required',          
        )
    ),
    'date' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Date required',           
        )
    ),
);
```

The 'title' validates correctly and flashes an error when the field is empty on submit.

However, the date allows me to save an empty date... Here are the form inputs:

```
echo $this->Form->input('date', array('type'=>'text', 'label'=>'Start Time', 'class'=>'datetimepicker google'));
echo $this->Form->input('end_date', array('type'=>'text', 'label'=>'End Time', 'class'=>'datetimepicker google'));
```

I've tried changing the validation rules to check for the date and even to check for alphanumeric characters, but it keeps letting me save empty dates, so I'm really not sure what I'm overlooking.

Comment: can you try this `'date' => array('rule' => 'date','message' => 'Enter a valid date','allowEmpty' => false)`

Comment: I tried your code above and now the validation fails even if there is a date in the field. I'm looking at the post request and there is a date string `data[Event][date]:2014-04-22 12:00 am`.

Comment: Please add the relevant code from the controller. also, have you tried the `required=>true` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what was wrong...

I had a line of code that was formatting the string to a date. By default, it would format and empty string into the default date of **12/31/1969**, which is why the validation was passing for empty values.

Now I have it set up to only convert to date format if a value is present... so something like this:

```
if ($this->data['Event']['date']) {
    $this->data['Event']['date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($this->data['Event']['date']));
}
```